# How can I make the progress bar reach the end of the snackbar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have managed to show several messages in a queue and each of the them has a progress bar. Each message closes after 4 seconds. But right now my big issue is that the progress bar line doesn't reach the end of the message but the message closes. I've added a short video and here is my code. Thanks for your ideas!

Video: https://streamable.com/ts8t92
1º: GenericSnackbarMessage

```
interface GenericSnackbarMessageProps {
  id: string;
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  title?: string;
  message?: string;
  icon: ReactNode;
  showLinearProgress?: boolean;
  closeMessageAfterTime?: boolean;
  isLastElement?: boolean;
  activeTimer?: boolean;
}

const useProgressBarStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    progressBar: {
      // Disable the transition animation from 100 to 0 inside the progress bar
      '&[aria-valuenow="0"]': {
        '& > $progressBarInner': {
          transition: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
    progressBarInner: {},
  })
);

const SlideTransition = (props: SlideProps) => <Slide {...props} direction="left" />;

const GenericSnackbarMessage = ({
  id,
  open,
  onClose,
  title = 'Title',
  message = 'Insert message here',
  icon,
  showLinearProgress,
  closeMessageAfterTime = true,
  isLastElement,
  activeTimer = true,
}: GenericSnackbarMessageProps) => {

  const { palette } = useTheme();

  const isDark = palette.mode === 'dark';

  const handleClose = useCallback((): void => {
    onClose();
  }, [onClose]);

  const classes = useProgressBarStyles();
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<number>(0);

  //this useEffect is used to animate the progress bar
  //we listen to the index and when it changes to 0 we start the animation again

  //to pose the timer when it's not the laat element but goes on with the first element

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!closeMessageAfterTime || !activeTimer || !isLastElement) return;

    const startTime = Date.now();
    const duration = 4000;

    const updateProgress = (): void => {
      const currentTime = Date.now();
      const elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
      const innerProgress = elapsedTime / duration * 100;

      setProgress(innerProgress >= 100 ? 100 : innerProgress);

      if (innerProgress >= 100 && elapsedTime >= duration) {
        console.log('Progress at timer end:', innerProgress);
        handleClose();
      }
    };

    const timerId = setInterval(updateProgress, 100);

    return (): void => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, [closeMessageAfterTime, activeTimer, isLastElement, handleClose]);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      TransitionComponent={SlideTransition}
    >
      <div>
        <Alert
          sx={{
            width: '487px',
            height: '104px',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            backgroundColor: isDark ? '#222221' : '#FDFDFD',
            color: isDark ? '#FFFFFF' : '#222221B2',
            padding: 0,
            boxShadow: isDark ? '-4px 4px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)' : '-4px 4px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)',
            '& .MuiAlert-message': {
              paddingBlock: 0,
              paddingLeft: icon ? 0 : 10,
            },
            '& .MuiTypography-root': { marginBottom: 0 },
            '& .MuiAlert-icon': {
              padding: 0,
              marginRight: 5,
            },
          }}
          icon={!!icon && (
            <Stack
              justifyContent="center"
              alignItems="center"
              style={{
                borderRadius: '100%',
                backgroundColor: alpha(palette.error.main, 0.10),
                width: '48px',
                height: '48px',
                marginTop: '28px',
                marginBottom: '28px',
                marginLeft: '40px',
                padding: '0px',
              }}
            >
              {icon}
            </Stack>
          )}
          action={(
            <CrossIcon
              style={{
              color: isDark ? '#FFFFFF' : '#222221B2',
              padding: '40px 40px 40px 0px',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              }}
              onClick={handleClose}
            />
          )}
        >
          <AlertTitle sx={{ paddingTop: 8 }}>
            <Typography variant='headings.h4' color={isDark ? '#FFFFFF' : '#222221B2'}>{title}</Typography>
          </AlertTitle>
          <Typography variant='captions.default' color={isDark ? '#FFFFFF' : '#222221B2'}>{message}</Typography>
        </Alert>
        {showLinearProgress
          && (
            <LinearProgress
              variant="determinate"
              className={classes.progressBar}
              value={progress}
              classes={{ bar: classes.progressBarInner }}
            />
          )}
      </div>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};

export default GenericSnackbarMessage;
export type { GenericSnackbarMessageProps };
interface SnackbarProviderProps{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

2º Provider

```
export const SnackbarProvider = ({ children }: SnackbarProviderProps): ReactElement => {

  //this state will hold the queue of snackbar messages
  const [snackbarQueue, setSnackbarQueue] = useState<Array<GenericSnackbarMessageProps>>([]);

  //to add a snackbar to the queue
  const addSnackbar = useCallback(
    (snackbarConfig: GenericSnackbarMessageProps): void => {
      setSnackbarQueue((prev) => [...prev, snackbarConfig]);
    },
    []
  );

  //to remove a snackbar from the queue in the useEffect
  const removeSnackbar = (id: string): void => {
    setSnackbarQueue((prev) => prev.filter((snackbar) => snackbar.id !== id));
  };

  //this context value will be passed to any component desiring to use the snackbar
   // the value of the context is an object with three methods: info, success, fail
  const contextValue: SnackbarContextType = useMemo(() => ({
    showGenericMessage: (snackbarConfig: GenericSnackbarMessageProps): void => {
      addSnackbar(snackbarConfig);
    },
    clearAllSnackbars:  (): void => {
      setSnackbarQueue([]);
    },
  }), [addSnackbar]);

  return (
    <SnackbarContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
      {snackbarQueue.length > 0
        && snackbarQueue.map((snackbar, index) => (
          <GenericSnackbarMessage
            key={snackbar.id}
            {...snackbar}
            title={`I'm number ${index}`}
            isLastElement={snackbarQueue.length - 1 === index}
            onClose={(): void => void removeSnackbar(snackbar.id)}
          />
      ))}

    </SnackbarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mariadev
It seems that there's a delay time of **css-transition** on LinearProgress component.

```
.css-8n2xj1-MuiLinearProgress-bar1 {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s linear;
    transition: transform .4s linear;
    transform-origin: left;
    background-color: #2065D1;
}
```

for example, if you change progress value from 40 to 60, it won't be changed **immediately**.
it has 400ms delay time to be changed to target value.
so you can change the code like followings.

- GenericSnackBarMessage

> ```
> const timerId = setInterval(() => {
>   const currentTime = Date.now();
>   const elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
>   const innerProgress = elapsedTime / duration * 100;
>
>   setProgress(innerProgress >= 100 ? 100 : innerProgress);
>
>   if (innerProgress >= 110 && elapsedTime >= duration) {
>     console.log('Progress at timer end:', innerProgress);
>     handleClose();
>   }
> }, 100);
> ```

Here I changed comparison value as 110,
because required total duration = 4000ms + 400ms = 4400ms (110%)

> ```
> if (innerProgress >= 110 && elapsedTime >= duration) {
>         console.log('Progress at timer end:', innerProgress);
>         handleClose();
> }
> ```

I hope this answer will help you.